# Display json data from a javascript file to html list

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following javascript/json array and would like to display it as an html list but im stuck:

```
    var myFunction = function() {
        var myList = [
            {
                'name': 'Emely',
            },
            {
                'name': 'John',
            },
            {
                'name': 'Stewart',  
            }
        ];
    var dataObject = JSON.parse(myList);
    var listItemString = $('#listItem').html();
    dataObject.forEach(buildNewList);
    function buildNewList(item, index) {
        var listItem = $('<li>' + listItemString + '</li>');
        var listItemTitle = $('.title', listItem);
        listItemTitle.html(item.name);
        $('#mydatalist').append(listItem);
    }
  };
```

i am not sure what im doing wrong.Ive been trying for three hours now.

my html is as follows:

```
<div id="listItem">
  <div class="row1">
    <div class="title"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but my list is still not displaying

Comment: You have defined a function, myFunction, by I do not see where you have called it.

Comment: That does not appear to be valid JSON. `JSON.parse` will throw a syntax error.

Comment: Your use of `JSON.parse` is suspicious.  This method takes a string and returns a Javascript object.  Yet you already have an object, `myList`, so I dont see what you are attempting to do.

Comment: @showdev `JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( myList ) )` round-trips just fine.

Comment: @StephenP Yes, because `stringify` converts a JS value into a JSON string. But the OP isn't using `stringify` and, as @EJK mentioned, parsing seems [unnecessary in this context](https://jsfiddle.net/bcd5xgad/) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is (**J**)ava(**S**)cript (**O**)bject (**N**)otation

It is a way to represent a Javascript object as a string, primarily so it can be stored or transmitted.
`JSON.stringify(object)` will turn a JS object into a string, while `JSON.parse(str)` will turn a string into a JS object.

In your case, you have an Array of Objects assigned to the variable `myList` — it is an *Object* (an array is an object), not a *JSON string*, so it doesn't need to be parsed as you are doing with `var dataObject = JSON.parse(myList);` ... it is *already* an object. `var dataObject = myList` would get you the object you want, but that's pointless because you could use `myList` directly.
You *would* need to parse that data if you had received it as a string through an AJAX call, but you are working directly in Javascript.

There are other problems with your code, as others have pointed out -- e.g. you have your `myFunction` but you never call it (as EJK commented) so none of your code will ever be executed.
You also reference `'#mydatalist'` but you have no HTML element with that ID, so your `append(...)` does nothing.

Comment: i totally understand.So what would you suggest as the solution?

Comment: @John -- I don't know ... there is a _**lot**_ wrong with it.  Another thing is that you do `$('#mydatalist').append(listItem);` -- but there _**is no**_ element with an ID of `mydatalist` so `.append(...)` gets invoked on _nothing_ and therefore nothing is added to the DOM.

Comment: ok,but what i am trying to understand is,if you were given that json array,how would you display it as an html list.

Comment: @John - what you need to understand is you _aren't_ being given a json array: myList is not a "JSON array" -- it is a Javascript **Object** (a JS array +is+ a JS object). JSON is a plain-text representation of a javascript object. You can `JSON.stringify(SomeJSobject)` which results in a plain-text String, send that String over the wire or save it to a file, then later `JSON.parse(theString)` to get the actual Object back. Because you _already_ have an object (var myList = [...] is an array-of-objects) you don't need to `.parse` it to produce an object.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
function buildNewList(item, index) {
    var listItem = $('<li><div class="row1"><div class="title">' + item+ '</div></div></li>');
    $('#mydatalist').append(listItem);
}

var myFunction = function() {
    var myList = '[
        {
            "name": "Emely"
        },
        {
            "name": "John"
        },
        {
            "name": "Stewart"
        }
    ]';
    var dataObject = JSON.parse(myList);
    var listItemString = $('#listItem').html();

    dataObject.forEach(buildNewList);

};
```